# Prove that a function is $\mathcal{C}^n$ using the reccurence

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$ and $f:\left[0,1\left[\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\right.\right.$ a $\mathrm{C}^{n} $  function. Let $g$ the application $\left[0,1\left[\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\right.\right.$ such that $g(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$ for each $x \neq 0$ and $g(0)=f^{\prime}(0)$.
Let $\mathrm{t}:\left[0,1\left[\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\right.\right.$ defined by $\mathrm{t}(x)=f(x)-\sum_{\ell=0}^{n} \frac{f^{(\ell)}(0)}{\ell !} x^{\ell}$, and $h$ defined by $h(x)=\frac{\mathrm{t}(x)}{x}$ if $x \neq 0$ and $h(0)=0 .$ Using [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule), prove that $h$ is a $\mathrm{C}^{n-1}$ function  on $[0,1[$, and $\forall 0 \leq k \leq n-1$ we have $h^{(k)}(0)=0$.

---

In $]0,1[$, it's okay. I still have a problem with $0$, I tried using L'Hôpital's rule, and the recurrence, but I didn't get the result. Any help!

I appreciate it.